# Rewrite rule nginx, token

Tags: proxy, nginx, http-proxy, rewrite

I have a java application which is behind nginx proxy pass.
When the URL is called the application automatically creates a path for the served content.

So when you call `https://somedomain.com` you get `https://somedomain.com/todayisaniceday`

This is the the proxy pass directive and the rewrite rule in my nginx:

```
    location /URI{
    proxy_pass      http://IP:PORT/URI;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9=\?]+)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
}
```

I'm implementing one token authentication mechanism.

What I would like to achieve is the following:

when you call:

`https://somedomain.com/something?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ`

The URL will stay and will be not rewritten by the java application.
So basically when there is this string `?jwt=` in the url it should keep it and everything behind it.

I was trying something like this:

`rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?jwt=$1 break;` but without success.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditionals in your location section:

```
if ($request_uri !~ (.+(jwt=).+) ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
}
```

You should change regex for request_uri accordingly to your needs

Comment: what do you mean by "You should change regex for request_uri accordingly to your needs" ?

Comment: It depends on what you are using in section `something`.
Regex like I've mentioned in my answer will find everything which does not contain "jwt=" string in request_uri and only then rewrite is done.

You need eventually fit this regular expression to suit your needs.